# Redux - Set state by depending actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to achieve the follow sequence of my data flow:

1. Get the record-id of react-router
2. Set this id as state property
3. If this property is set, all other dependent components, with it's own reducer and actions should get their data depending on the id

   ```
   componentWillMount() {

       this.props.actions.setItemId(this.props.params.id);

       if(this.props.id){
           this.props.fetchItemInformations(this.props.id);
       }
   }
   ```

I am aware that this flow won't work but I've no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this but if your problem is due to async issues then you can use middleware such as Redux Thunk. This will essentially allow you to chain your actions i.e. once the id is set then dispatch another action to do X.

See here - https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Alternatively, you could do your if statement within the  componentWillReceiveProps () lifecycle event and check if it has been set there. If it has then dispatch your next action...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to fetch the property `record-id` from react-router (This is a url hash I assume?).

You can directly pass the this prop to all the children (as a prop) and handle the value in the children as you wish. To do this, 
Pass the prop as well when rendering `{ this.props.children }`; something like

`{ React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { record-id: record-id }) }`

This I'd say is the best practice; if you want to pass the `record-id` to other components (that are not direct children) of your parent component; you need to fire an action and handle the action to update relevant reducer states. Hope that helps.